# Count number of groups (with specific TAG) within a specific format (with Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, phylogeny

Hello everyone I need some help :

I do not know if you are familiar with phylogenetic tree but here is an exemple:

```
   /-YP_001604167.1
  |
  |--YP_001604351.1
--|
  |      /-seq_TAG2_Canis_taurus
  |   /-|
  |  |   \-seq_TAG2_Canis_austracus
   \-|
     |   /-YP_001798528.1
      \-|
        |   /-YP_009173671.1
         \-|
           |   /-seq_TAG1_Mus_musculus
            \-|
              |   /-seq_TAG1_Mus_griseus
               \-|
                 |   /-seq_TAG2_Canis_canis
                  \-|
                    |   /-seq_TAG2_Canis_familiaris
                     \-|
                        \-seq_TAG2_Canis_lupus
```

And this tree is coded by a specific format called newick :

```
'(YP_001604167.1,YP_001604351.1,((seq_TAG2_Canis_austracus,seq_TAG2_Canis_taurus),(YP_001798528.1,(YP_009173671.1,(seq_TAG1_Mus_musculus,(seq_TAG1_Mus_griseus,(seq_TAG2_Canis_lupus,(seq_TAG2_Canis_familiaris,seq_TAG2_Canis_canis))))))));'
```

- Explanation of the format:

The tree ends with a semicolon. The bottommost node in this tree is an interior node, not a tip. Interior nodes are represented by a pair of matched parentheses. Between them are representations of the nodes (`seq_names`) that are immediately `descended` from that `node`, separated by `commas`.

son if I have something like :

```
(A,(B,C));
```

Then it means that `B` and `C` are more closely related each other and `A` is  the most distant.

And the idea of my question was to find a way using for instance python to count the number of groups with the same "`TAG_number`" that are more close to each other than any other `TAG_number` or `YP_number` nodes.

For instance, the `TAG2` in representated in `2 groups` where `(seq_TAG2_Canis_taurus, seq_TAG2_Canis_austracus)` are together and the second group `(seq_TAG2_Canis_canis, (seq_TAG2_Canis_familiaris , seq_TAG2_Canis_lupus))` are together. For the `TAG1` as you can see, none of them is nested together because `seq_TAG1_Mus_griseus` is more close to the group `(seq_TAG2_Canis_canis, (seq_TAG2_Canis_familiaris , seq_TAG2_Canis_lupus))` than it is with the other `TAG1 seq_TAG1_Mus_musculus`.

So the result should be something like :

```
groups for TAG_1 : 0 
groups for TAG_2 : 2
```

I know that some packages in Python or R are available in order to tell if TAG_number are in "`monophyletic groups`" but there is nothing to tells the number of groups within the tree if `TAG_number` groups are splitted within the tree.

If you have any idea in order to do that? Thank you very much.

Other part of the question :

Now I have a `Species phylogeny` such as  :

```
|         /-Canis_taurus
|      /-|
|     |   \-Canis_astracus
|   /-|
|  |  |   /-Canis_africus
|  |   \-|
|  |     |   /-Canis_familiaris
 \-|      \-|
   |         \-Canis _lupus
   |
   |   /-Canis_canis
    \-|
       \-Lupus_lupus
```

and The idea is within each `monophyletic groups` assesed in the previous process, to count within clades formed by the MRCA of the clades in the species phylogeny the number of nodes.

So I have `2 groups`:

The first:

```
#    /-TAG2, seq_TAG2_Canis_austracus
# --|
#    \-TAG2, seq_TAG2_Canis_taurus
#
```

Here `Canis_austracus` and `Canis_taurus` share a `MRCA` in the species phylogeny and this ancestor forms the clade composed by `2 species` (`Canis_austracus and Canis_taurus`)

So Nb species within species phylogenetic tree = `2`

```
#    /-TAG2, seq_TAG2_Canis_lupus
# --|
#   |   /-TAG2, seq_TAG2_Canis_familiaris
#    \-|
#       \-TAG2, seq_TAG2_Canis_canis
```

Here the 3 taxa share a `MRCA` and this ancestor forms the clade composed by all species in the species phylogeny (7)

So Nb species within species phylogenetic tree = `7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe get_monophyletic of ete3 is what you need?
http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/reference/reference_tree.html?highlight=get_monophyletic#ete3.TreeNode.get_monophyletic

from ete3 import Tree
    import re

```
# build tree
t = Tree("(YP_001604167.1,YP_001604351.1,"
         "((seq_TAG2_Canis_austracus,seq_TAG2_Canis_taurus),"
         "(YP_001798528.1,(YP_009173671.1,(seq_TAG1_Mus_musculus,"
         "(seq_TAG1_Mus_griseus,(seq_TAG2_Canis_lupus,"
         "(seq_TAG2_Canis_familiaris,seq_TAG2_Canis_canis))))))));")

# set tag as leave attribute
for leaf in t:
    # get tag from name
    tag = re.search('TAG[0-9]', leaf.name)
    tag = tag.group(0) if tag else None
    leaf.add_features(tag=tag)

# show the hole tree
print(t.get_ascii(attributes=["name", "tag"], show_internal=False))

# show all monophyletic groups for tag=TAG2
for node in t.get_monophyletic(values=["TAG2"], target_attr="tag"):
    print(node.get_ascii(attributes=["tag", "name"], show_internal=False))


#    /-TAG2, seq_TAG2_Canis_austracus
# --|
#    \-TAG2, seq_TAG2_Canis_taurus
#
#    /-TAG2, seq_TAG2_Canis_lupus
# --|
#   |   /-TAG2, seq_TAG2_Canis_familiaris
#    \-|
#       \-TAG2, seq_TAG2_Canis_canis
```